# KReporter integration with SurgarCRM on Centos

Tags: linux, centos, reporting, crm, sugarcrm

I'm trying to install the Kreporter 4.0 plugin with SugarCRM CE on Centos. The first step is to install the KREST API 2.2, which I have been unsuccessful in getting to work. It installs correctly, but when I visit /KREST/sysinfo or /KREST/index.php I get an HTTP 500 error. I have already checked all file permissions and Selinux settings. From my testing, the error seems to be occuring during the file includes (in index.php), but I'm not getting any error reporting in either the sugarcrm.log or apache error logs. Also the core and base packages properly install, but reports fail (most likely because the KREST API is not working).

Has anyone had success in installing this plugin on Centos or other linux platforms? If so, can you provide some details on the installation process. They don't provide much details on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on the PHP errors and restart the webserver. Mostly this is a permissions issue. Set permission 755 to the CRM root folder and check.